# jqplot Background Color Zones?

Tags: background, jqplot

I would like to be able to have several different "zones" indicated by the background on my jqplot bar chart.

I have looked through the documentation, but have been unable to easily identify a way to do this.

Is there a simple "fill" function or parameter that would allow me to set the background in several bands of horizontal color (various heights)?

Thanks in advance.

FG

Comment: Check my related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837997/jqplot-how-to-color-parts-of-background-grid-with-several-different-colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a similar approach as I suggest in [the answer to a different question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428034/613495)

[A direct link to the code sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/XzdHt/)

You would then set the sizes of the underlying lines accordingly to highlight your regions.
This approach is for example used by @Katya presented in the link under one of the comments to the aforementioned answer.

[Direct link to Katya's code sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/buzyonok/WdLnm/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the rectangle overlay developed by Bruno Harbulot : https://bitbucket.org/harbulot/jqplot

Here is a jsFiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/K2cVL/1/