# jqPlot : how to color parts of background / grid with several different colors

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, graph, jqplot

I am using the excellent [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) plug-in, and the only feature that I didn't find in the [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) is "how to color parts of background / grid with several different colors"

The x-axis units of my graphs are dates. I would like to highlight the weekend part (only) of the grid by changing the background grid color if it is possible.

Or anyone would have another idea?

Thanks

**EDIT WITH FINAL ANSWER**

Based on the Boro's suggestion, I developed a better way to highlight a part of the background using the "line" option instead of "verticalLine" option. The fact is that with "verticalLine", developers must deal with the line width.So, it is difficult to obtain what you need because the width of the line spreads from the centre of the line and not from a border.

["Line" option](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasOverlay-js.html#Line) permits to set a start and end points to set the exact part of the background to highlight. The width parameter is still used to display the line as a column, but it spread horizontally, not vertically.

About the "lineWidth" properties, the value is defined in pixel. Therefore, you can set the value with the graph container height to be sure and set the "y" value of the "start" and "end" properties with an average of your series data or an approximate middle range of your yaxis.

I updated the Boro's fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/141/)

```
                grid:                 
                {
                    drawGridLines: true,        // wether to draw lines across the grid or not.
                    gridLineColor: '#cccccc',   // Color of the grid lines.
                    backgroundColor: "#eee",
                    borderColor: '#999999',     // CSS color spec for border around grid.
                    borderWidth: 2.0,           // pixel width of border around grid.
                    shadow: true,               // draw a shadow for grid.
                    shadowAngle: 45,            // angle of the shadow.  Clockwise from x axis.
                    shadowOffset: 1.5,          // offset from the line of the shadow.
                    shadowWidth: 3,             // width of the stroke for the shadow.
                    shadowDepth: 3,             // Number of strokes to make when drawing shadow.
                                                // Each stroke offset by shadowOffset from the last.
                    shadowAlpha: 0.07,          // Opacity of the shadow
                },
                canvasOverlay: {
                    show: true,
                    objects:

                            [
                                {
                                    line:
                                    {
                                        start : [new Date('2012-01-12').getTime(),20],                                                
                                        stop : [new Date('2012-01-13').getTime(),20],                                                
                                        lineWidth: 1000,
                                        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.45)',
                                        shadow: false,
                                        lineCap : 'butt'
                                    }
                                },                                    
                                {
                                    line:
                                    {
                                        start : [new Date('2012-01-13').getTime(),20],                                                
                                        stop : [new Date('2012-01-14').getTime(),20],                                                
                                        lineWidth: 1000,
                                        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.45)',
                                        shadow: false,
                                        lineCap : 'butt'
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                }
```

[image: Result sample]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the sample shown by @Katya in the code under [my answer to a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428034/613495) maight be helpful for you.

[Direct link to the sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/7/)

**EDIT**

With regards to the second part you would need to use a `verticalLine` and set its `x` value as milliseconds, [as presented here](http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/135/). Then you need to worry about selecting appropriate `lineWidth`.

Comment: Thank you very much Boro, It's exactly what I need. Sorry to reply so late, I was in vacation.

Comment: Hi, FYI, I have just edited my post with a my final solution. Thanks

Comment: @Bouillou thanks very much for sharing it with us. Very nice code. I see you actually noticed that the stop is useful when I tried it didn't work right to me with `verticalLine` but with `line` it works great. I wonder how should the value of the `lineWidth` be evaluated? BTW if I could I would +1 the question once more -- for the code and sample. :)

Comment: The lineWidth is defined in pixel. Therefore, you can set the graph container height property, and set the "y" value with an average or an approximate middle range value of your series. $('#graph-container').height();

Comment: That was my initial thinking but trying it on your sample the line is drawn only slightly above the middle.