# jqPlot from line to dotted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, dotted-line

I have a graph where I show projections for several statistics. The statistics up to this year are certain, but from 2012 and beyond, they are just a projection, and therefore not certain. I want to have a line when the statistics are certain, and become dotted when the projection starts.

Is this possible? Or do I have to create a new line that is dotted and starts after this year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to split the data into two different series with different options for each.

Answer (score 0):

That's what i feared. Somebody found a nice way to just color the background instead, so went for that. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837997/jqplot-how-to-color-parts-of-background-grid-with-several-different-colors)