# I need area plot with treshold changing area background color

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am looking for option in jqplot (or another free js chart library) to show normal 2d area plot (line plot with background filled under the line) but with some treshold (for example y = 2) above which plot changes its background color.

Answer (score 0):

I have got some headache working on slightly similar problemit few month ago. There is no options in JQPlot to do that, but with the @Boro help, I found a woraround.

Here is the related topic : [jqPlot : how to color parts of background / grid with several different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837997/jqplot-how-to-color-parts-of-background-grid-with-several-different-colors)

I had to add the fiddle in comment due to StackOverFlow restriction

Comment: No - I need to change fill color of a series with some treshold - for now I've done script shich cuts the series into smaller parts and groups them in "over threshold" and "under threshold"... not nice but it works