# how to change color of particular interval in primefaces line chart?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot, linechart

I'm using primefaces 6.0 and tried to create line chart,its working fine. But i want to customize the color of valid interval.

my xhtml

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{showChartMB.newModelAgr}" style="height:300px;width:350px;" />
```

method for chart:

```
private void createLineModelsAgr(int uid, List<Report> newRangeAgr) {
    newModelAgr = initLinearModelAgr(uid, newRangeAgr);
    newModelAgr.setExtender("chartExtender");
    newModelAgr.setTitle("Albumin/Globumin ratio");
    newModelAgr.setLegendPosition("e");
    org.primefaces.model.chart.Axis yAxis = newModelAgr.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(1);
    yAxis.setMax(4);
    yAxis.setLabel("Range");
    org.primefaces.model.chart.Axis xAxis = newModelAgr.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setMin(1);
    xAxis.setMax(10);
    newModelAgr.setAnimate(true);
    newModelAgr.setSeriesColors("#4bb2c5");
    xAxis.setLabel("Time -->");

}
```

Here i want to change the background color for range 2 to 3 along yAxis.

Comment: First see if it is possible in plain jqplot

Comment: i dont have much knowledge in jqplot would you please help me in this case .

Comment: Your 'not much knowledge' is more than mine 'next to none'. So it would mean using a searchengine for you, which is not where I want to spend my time on, sorry.

Comment: Bit I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534056/jqplot-background-color-zones