# Background opacity for any Jqplot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqplot

How it is possible to change background opacity for Jqplot charts? (I mean only for background).

Possible is change a color, or do backgroud transparent:

```
grid: { background: 'transparent' }
```

But what about opacity? I tried this, but does not work:

```
    $('.jqplot-grid-background').css({
        'opacity': '0.4'
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I already solved it with rgba definition: background: 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2)'

Answer (score 1):

you have to give like

```
seriesColors:['rgba(100, 150, 100, 0.75)']
```

check this link [jqPlot - How to change opacity or z-index of canvasOverlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426192/jqplot-how-to-change-opacity-or-z-index-of-canvasoverlay)

Answer (score 0):

I already solved by rgba defintion:

```
background: 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2)'
```

The last parametr is opacity, the sample show background as light grey.